# Angularjs alternative to md-virtual-repeat due to UI issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a relatively large array (lets say 500 items) of complex objects and currently using [md-virtual-repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdVirtualRepeat) to render the UI and scroll though the items (**of a fixed size**) without a problem. Due to UI changes in the system it is required to add item expansion ability (resizing, something like collapse\expand for each item). For small arrays (up to ~20) the scrolling still works without issues. The problem starts for larger arrays and some items expanded. The scrolling becomes choppy and not all expanded data is shown since the virtual repeater replaces items while scrolling. I'm looking for a workaround of this issue, OR an alternative solution (maybe another library?). Any ideas?

Comment: we use angular-vs-repeat

Comment: @PetrAveryanov thanks but still the same limitation of "all rendered elements must have the same height/width or the sizes of the elements must be known up front". I need the option to expand\collapse and the height can be different

Comment: 'angular-vs-repeat' allow collapse-expand but, yes, you need to know item sizes, e.g. 100px collapsed, 200px expanded. You can also change expanded height depending on data (not rendering). If this is not enough for you - you probably should put more details in your question.